# How to not display current document in view?

Tags: xpages

I have a view panel on a xpage.  The view panel is meant to display "similar" issues.  Each of these documents has the same value for issueNum, I have a view categortized by issueNum and the view panel has the Filter by Category Name set so it only displays documents with the same value in issueNum.   All works great excpect the view (as expected) is displaying the current issue being displayed on the xpage.

Is there any way to not display the current document being displayed on the xpage  in the view panel of "similar" documents?  If so how?

Comment: Best way I can think to do it is to, instead of getting the collection through the default methods, bind your view to a calculation where you get the view and category collection through SSJS, then loop through the view until you find the current document and remove it from the collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Switch to a repeat control where you can control every row manually. It also gives you better flexibility in formatting
- use the "var" attribute to get hands on the row value and compute the styleClass to a class that has display : none; defined. You need to compute the rowClasses attribute.

Comment: Which one did you pick?